# How Can I use Solve/Reduce Output

Tags: functions, equation-solving

Suppose I want `x` and `y` to be rationals

```
Solve[ x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}, Rationals]
```

I am told:

> ```
> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.
> ```

and given a "solution"

> ```
> {{y -> ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[ 1 - x^2], (x | y) ∈ Rationals && -1 <= x <= 1]},
>  {y -> ConditionalExpression[ Sqrt[ 1 - x^2], (x | y) ∈ Rationals && -1 <= x <= 1]}}
> ```

Try `Reduce`

```
Reduce[ x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}, Rationals]
```

`Mathematica` returns

> ```
> (x | y) ∈ Rationals && -1 <= x <= 1 && (y == -Sqrt[1 - x^2] || y == Sqrt[1 - x^2])
> ```

Not much more help. Next try to see what `Mathematica` can do make a list of solutions:

```
FindInstance[ x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}, Rationals, 10]
```

I am told that:

> ```
> FindInstance::fwsol: Warning: FindInstance found only 2 instance(s), but it was not able
> to prove 10 instances do not exist.
> ```

and given the two solutions found

> ```
> {{x -> -1, y -> 0}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}}
> ```

Mathematica did not help too much here - but does show me that at least some solutions exist and that there may be more.

- Is this all I am going to get out of `Mathematica` in this case?
- Is this an answer that a mathematican wants to know and `Mathematica` has done its work?
- If I better understood `Mathematica`, could I use its other functions on the solution from `Solve` or `Reduce` to help me learn more about the solutions? (or do I just have to get my hands dirty and do the work myself - in this example it is pretty easy to find the general solution by hand)
- And maybe more generally, which `Mathematica` functions are able to do something more with this type of output from `Solve` or `Reduce`? (e.g. can I plot it?)

Comment: You already know the procedure for parametrically generating Pythagorean triples, I take it?

Comment: A naive way. `Union@(Abs @ {x/y, z/w} /. 
   FindInstance[(x/y)^2 + (z/w)^2 == 1 && 1 < x < 100 && 
     x != y != z != w != 0, {x, y, z, w}, Integers, 10])`

Comment: BTW, *Mathematica* is not a mathematician. It may help you, but it is not a replacement for your math knowledge.

Answer (score 11):

### Direct solutions using `Solve`

Since there are infinitely many solutions to the problem at hand we prefer to choose a bound on the solution space, i.e. we solve `(x/y)^2 + (z/w)^2 == 1` in `Integers` and select only solutions satisfying  `x/y <= z/w` and `0 < x <= y <= 50` and `z <= w <= 50`. It takes a bit  but we know we have found all solutions satisying given criteria.

```
Union[{#1/#2, #3/#4} & @@@ Solve[(x/y)^2 + (z/w)^2 == 1 && 0 < x <= y <= 50 &&
                                  x/y <= z/w && z <= w <= 50, {x, y, z, w},
                                                                  Integers][[All, All, 2]]]
```

> ```
> {{9/41, 40/41}, {7/25, 24/25}, {12/37, 35/37}, {5/13, 12/13}, {8/17, 15/17},
>  {3/5, 4/5}, {20/29, 21/29}}
> ```

Now we can check if these are solutions :

```
And @@ (#1^2 + #2^2 == 1 & @@@ %)
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Well, indeed.

**Edit 1**

### Solutions generated by `Table` of Pythagorean triples

Some more efficient way of generating rational solutions of the equation `x^2 + y^2 == 1` is based on Pythagorean triples. We can write a table of numbers of the form e.g. $(\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2},\frac{2 x y}{x^2+y^2})$ and select only distinct ones :

```
pts = Union @ Flatten[Table[{(x^2 - y^2)/(x^2 + y^2), (2 x y)/(x^2 + y^2)},
                            {y, 20}, {x, 20}], 1];
Length @ pts
```

> ```
> 255
> ```

```
ParametricPlot[ {Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
                                   Epilog -> { Red, PointSize[0.006], Point @ pts}]
```

[image]

### Solutions generated by Fibbonacci numbers

We could find only special solutions making use of observations by Dujella that Fibbonacci numbers $F_{n}$ generate distinct [Pythagorean triples](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagoreanTriple.html)   $(F_{n} F_{n+3},2F_{n+1}F_{n+2},F_{n+1}^2+F_{n+2}^2)$  although not exhaustively. 
Thus proceeding this way we can find   arbitrary many distinct solutions quite effectively.
We find the first `100` such solutions :

```
ptsF = 
  Table[{( Fibonacci[n] Fibonacci[n + 3])/( Fibonacci[n + 1]^2 + Fibonacci[n + 2]^2),
         ( 2Fibonacci[n + 1] Fibonacci[n + 2])/( Fibonacci[n + 1]^2 + Fibonacci[n + 2]^2)},
         {n, 100}];

And @@ (#1^2 + #2^2 == 1 & @@@ ptsF)
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Let's write some of them :

```
ptsF[[;; 20]]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, Pi/2}, Epilog -> {Red, Point @ ptsF}]
```

[image]

**Edit 2**

Since there could be some kind of misunderstanding I add another way to visualize the solution set for various numbers of solutions constructed with tables of Pythagorean triples.

```
Clear[pt]
pt[k_Integer /; OddQ[k] && k > 0] := 
  Union @ Flatten[ 
            Table[{(x^2 - y^2)/(x^2 + y^2), (2 x y)/(x^2 + y^2)}, 
                                       {y, -k, k, 2}, {x, -k, k} ], 1]
```

Now we check what is distribution of solution points in various cases, e.g.

```
GraphicsRow[ Table[ 
                    ParametricPlot[ {Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi},
                                                      PlotStyle -> Thin, 
                                                      Epilog -> { Red, Point @ p} ],
                   {p, {pt[9], pt[17], pt[55]}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Also `Union@({(x/y), (z/w)} /. {ToRules[
     Reduce[(x/y)^2 + (z/w)^2 == 1 && 0 < x <= y <= 50 && x/y <= z/w &&
        z <= w <= 50, {x, y, z, w}, Integers]]})`

Comment: Thank you Belisarius for your guidance. The andser is helpful for solving this problem and I had not thought of this particular way of proceeding.

Comment: I want to add that I had used this particular example to get a solution with Domain restrictions. My question, while rather fuzzy to say the least, was what can I do with those kinds of solutions (with Domain or similar restictions) as input to other Mathematica Functions?

Comment: @RonBurns Consider registering your account, then you'll have more opportunities to benefit from using this site. Could you ask more precisely ?  As I wrote there were infinitely many solutions, so to choose only specific ones you have to add conditions to `Solve` or `Reduce`. In this case there is no way to find all possible solutions.

Comment: @Artes, "In this case there is no way to find all possible solutions" - that's why I suggested to the OP that he might want to use the rational parametrization for generating Pythagorean triples; the suggestion was not heeded, though. To reiterate belisarius: "*Mathematica* is not a mathematician. It may help you, but it is not a replacement for your math knowledge."

Comment: @J.M. This is a nice question and it makes me to wonder why it's got only `1` upvote so far. He realizes your suggestion that "in this example it is pretty easy to find the general solution by hand".

Comment: In any event: solving Diophantine equations in general is hard, and *Mathematica* will often need a little assistance from the user.