# How Can I Use Conditional with Rational Domain Restrictions

Tags: functions

I am reasking this question in a new thread. My previous post  [How Can I Use Solve/Reduce Output?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/how-can-i-use-solve-reduce-output) seemed to have led to a an interesting dissussion of how to (better) solve the problem that produced the output rather than in how to use the output further as I had intended. [Perhaps it indirectly answered my question by telling me that if I wanted to know more I needed to reformulate the problem and the solution as qiven was as far as Mathematica could go with the original formulation.]

My questions is "Can I use the following result for further Mathematica calculations?" [i.e. I am not particularly interested in this solution other than using it as an **example** expression of a conditional with restricted domain.]

```
solQ= (x | y) \[Element] Rationals && -1 <= x <= 
 1 && (y == -Sqrt[1 - x^2] || y == Sqrt[1 - x^2])
```

I do know of one Mathematica function  that will accept this as input:

```
In[9]:= FindInstance[solQ, {x, y}, 10]

During evaluation of In[9]:= FindInstance::fwsol: Warning: FindInstance found only 3
instance(s), but it was not able to prove 10 instances do not exist. >>   

Out[9]= {{x -> -1, y -> 0}, {x -> 100/2501, y -> 2499/2501}, {x -> 1, 
  y -> 0}}
```

[However (as an aside) this function has strange behavior when I ask for 50 instances it can only find 2 for sure!]

```
In[11]:= FindInstance[solQ, {x, y}, 50]

During evaluation of In[11]:= FindInstance::fwsol: Warning: FindInstance found only 2
instance(s), but it was not able to prove 50 instances do not exist. >>

Out[11]= {{x -> -1, y -> 0}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}}
```

Are there other Mathematica functions that will accept these types of solutions (like solQ) as a valid input expressions that would help me further explore the solution? Perhaps some graphics functions? Perhaps in an Assumption? ...?

Perhaps the solution as given above satisfies a Mathematician (which I am not) by "proving" that a solution exits and giving a few examples?

Thank you all for your patience with these rather poorly defined questions [coming from a 75 year old physicist in retirement, with no cohort for discussion, just trying to (re)learn some math and Mathematica.]

Comment: @RonBurns `solQ` is a valid `Mathematica` expression. You can retrieve information from that, e.g. if you evaluate `Plot[List @@ solQ[[3, All, 2]], {x, -1, 1}, Evaluated -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]`. Does this answer your question ?

Comment: @Ron Burn `FindInstance[ solQ, {x, y}, 10]` returns something, not exceptionally interesting, but it is better than nothing. As I demonstrated in my answer to your former question, you can still find more interesting results than `FindInstance` or `Solve` directly do. If you want to get an information from `solQ` you can do it but in general there is no direct procedure. If you don't like it, perhaps you'll have to wait much for more robust versions of `Mathematica` or any other computer algebra system otherwise you have to accustom with similar issues trying more ingenious ways.

Comment: @Ron Burns If playing with `Mathematica` syntax is too hard, you can make use of  free-form input  or `WolframAlpha` query, shorthands (`=`) or (`==`) to find out something more from `solQ`.

Comment: @Artes Thank you for your continuing help. Again the suggestions do help me see the something more about the solutions and I am aware of those approaches,  but they do not restrict their answer to my Domain of interest. I think you have answered my question in terms by "waiting for a ... " and  I take that to mean that solQ is far as current version can go.  I have been using Mathematica since Version 1.3.  It is not so much the syntax, but the enormous size (numer of functions/packages) and a documentation that does not seem to be complete for many cases of new functionality.

Comment: @RonBurns `Solve` and `Reduce` are powerful functions, but not as much as to give the full solution to your problem. In several cases when you restrict your domain of interest to `Rationals` they can give you the full solutions, but not always. It is not surprising that it cannot find all solutions however you should be pleased with `solQ` returned by `Reduce`. You shouldn't espect `Mathematica` to return  all list of solutions : first : there are infinitely many solutions, second : they are apparently dense. You remember that the number of solutions found with `P-triples` was finite.

Comment: @RonBurns On the other hand `solQ` is just the full solution expressed symbolically. No computer ever will help you to find an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @Artes Yes I do understand the computer is not going to list an infinite number of solutions. I was just hoping that there may be some way to continute to investigate these solutions (like solQ), say by RegionPlot or ... either by setting Asumptions or using Options. I was unclear if Mathematica had reached its limit of if I just could not find the appropriate way to proceed. Again thank you for the input.

Comment: How could the result be different from `Plot[List @@ solQ[[3, All, 2]], {x, -1, 1}, Evaluated -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]` ?  You hopefully understand that plotting an infinite number of solutions in a finite range (precisely : in a compact set) cannot be different from that whole circle.  I demonstrated some ways to proceed further in the answer to the former question. In any case  evaluate `pts = Union @ Flatten[Table[{(x^2 - y^2)/(x^2 + y^2), (2 x y)/(x^2 + y^2)}, {y, 300}, {x, 300}], 1];` and then `ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, Pi/2}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point@pts}]`

Comment: It is assumed in my answer that you can find out that plotting all the red points covers the whole circle `X^2+y^2 == 1`. And it is assumed that you understand the expression `solQ`. To resume my answer : there is no direct way (at present) to work with `solQ`. There are some facilities like  `free-form input` or `WolframAlpha query` but they don't return exactly what you can get with `ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, Pi/2}, Epilog -> {Red, Point @ pts}]`.

Comment: @Artes I think your comments make a good answer to this question. If you do not decide to post an answer, please consider to close this one (as a duplicate).