# How to define a function based on the output of DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction

I would like to define a function based on the output of the following DSolve call:

`DSolve[{b Varx^2 - 2 b Varx x'[t] + b x'[t]^2 + m x''[t] == 0, 
  x[0] == x0, x'[0] == V0x}, x[t], t]`

I've tried to do the following:

`x[t_] := DSolve[{b Varx^2 - 2 b Varx x'[t] + b x'[t]^2 + m x''[t] == 0,
    x[0] == x0, x'[0] == V0x}, x[t], t]`

It showed the message: `$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded.`, so I believe I'm not doing it the right.

Any ideas?

Comment: @belisarius ...!#@*(&@#^%

Comment: @rm-rf [Do you need some help?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4272067/353410)

Comment: Specifically, you need the answer [Using the result of functions that return replacement rules](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/5) in the linked question.

Comment: Also see: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9035/5

Answer (score 3):

You did not give numerical values for some of the parameters, so I made up some. For some, you might not get solutions, or get complex solution, so that is something you can look into since I do not know the physics of the problem.

```
Clear[x, t, b, varx, m, v0x];
y[t_] = x[t] /. First@DSolve[{b varx^2 - 2 b varx x'[t] + b x'[t]^2 + m x''[t] == 0,
      x[0] == x0, x'[0] == v0x}, x[t], t]
```

gives

```
(b t varx - m Log[m/(v0x - varx)] + m Log[b t - m/(-v0x + varx)])/b
```

Then you can use the function `y[t]`

```
parms = {b -> 1, varx -> 2, m -> 1, x0 -> 1, v0x -> 0};
Plot[y[t] /. parms, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
D[y[t] /. parms, t]    
Out[48]= 2 + 1/(-(1/2) + t)
```

etc...

Answer (score 2):

Following Nasser's answer, here is a minor variation:

```
 x[tt_, {b_, varx_, m_, x0_, v0x_}] := Module[{}, 
   x[t_, {b, varx, m, x0, v0x}] = 
     Block[{x, t}, 
       x[t] /. First@
         DSolve[{b varx^2 - 2 b varx x'[t] + b x'[t]^2 + m x''[t] == 0, 
           x[0] == x0, x'[0] == v0x}, x[t], t]
     ];
   x[tt, {b, varx, m, x0, v0x}]
 ]
```

Then you can evaluate it by:

```
parms = {1, 2, 1, 1, 0};

x[4, parms]

Plot[x[t, parms], {t, 0, 1}]
```

etc. Note that ODE is computed just once for each parameter vector.