# The /. syntax in numerical methods

Tags: export, syntax

I have an analytical approximation method for solving an ODE and want to compare this to an NDSolve solution, but the syntax is confusing me. To get the solution from NDSolve, I define the ODE as eqn and use the following command to solve for O2n;

```
s = NDSolve[{eqn == 0, O2n[rn] == 0, O2n[ro] == po/omega}, 
  O2n, {r, rn, ro}]

Af = Plot[{(O2n[r]) /. s}, {r, rn, ro}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"Numerical"}]]
```

This works fine, but the /. syntax confuses me a little - what exactly does it signify, and how can I manipulate this? Specifically, I want to subtract my analytical function p[r] from this solution over the same range (rn - ro) to see how much they differ. Ideally I'd like to be able to export this data and analyze it further - can anyone explain the syntax to me, and how I might go about comparing the twain? Thank you!

Comment: Closely related: [(3175)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3175/121), [(6669)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6669/121), [(9035)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9035/121)

Comment: ...and [what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users#answer-18706)

Comment: Plot prints table of values..NDSolve returns O2n[ro]->Something...check `Table[O2n[r]) /. s, {r, rn, ro}]`..you are replacing your dependent variable with your independent variable which you have liberty to assign.

Comment: Ah cheers - ReplaceAll documentation not very illuminating coming from a MATLAB background, but that link is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are asking two questions, one of which is a candidate for closure (namely the `ReplaceAll` part)... to answer your second part (perhaps after an edit or another question), working code would be very useful.