# How can I find the $c$ such $Max[Fibonacci[Range[c]]] = 13$?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, number-theory

How can I  find the  $c$ such

```
 Max[Fibonacci[Range[c]]] = 13
```

I tried `Reduce` but there is an error message

```
Reduce[Max[Fibonacci[Range[c]]] == 13, c, Integers]
```

[image]

Comment: `Select[Fibonacci[Range[100]], # < =13 &] // Length`

Comment: if you are sure that the number belong to the sequence 'Solve[Fibonacci[x] == 13, x]'   works, even if mathematica gives you a warning message that some solutions may not be found( there is only 1 solution anyway).

Comment: @Alucard - Fibonacci is not limited to integer arguments. Fibonacci is real-valued for all real `x`. For example, `Plot[{Fibonacci[x], 13}, {x, -13, 10}, PlotRange -> All]`

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" *)
```

@Alucard suggested using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
Solve[Fibonacci[x] == 13, x]

(* Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may 
  not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

{{x -> Root[{-13 + Fibonacci[#1] &, -12.5223655802437480606062641933}]}} *)
```

Although not the desired solution, this is a solution of the equation.

```
Fibonacci[-12.5223655802437480606062641933]

(* 13.0000000000000000000000000 *)
```

Restricting `x` to a positive range

```
Solve[{Fibonacci[x] == 13, 1 <= x <= 13}, x]

(* Solve::nint: Warning: Solve used numeric integration to show that the solution 
  set found is complete.

{{x -> 7}} *)
```

Restricting x to also be an integer eliminates the warning message

```
Solve[{Fibonacci[x] == 13, 1 <= x <= 13}, x, Integers]

(* {{x -> 7}} *)
```

Comment: This fails for large Fibonacci numbers like `31940434634990099905`.

Comment: `Solve[{Fibonacci[x] == 31940434634990099905, 
  1 <= x <= 200}, x, Integers]`

Comment: I see that I used too large a bound on `x`.  Thanks.

Comment: @BobHanlon when i run `Solve[Fibonacci[x] == 13, x]` i get `x->7` , why your solution is different? i am using version 11.1

Comment: @Alucard - it is a version difference. As stated in my answer, I used v11.2.0. I just checked with v11.1.1 and v10.4.1 and obtained the same result as you did with v11.1. The answer with v11.2.0 is not wrong ("some solutions may not be found"), merely different. There is nothing in the statement `Solve[Fibonacci[x] == 13, x]` that requires `x` to be integer.

Answer (score 4):

It seems simpler to calculate rather than solve:

```
Clear[invFib];
invFib::notFib = "`` is not a Fibonacci number";
invFib[F_Integer] := With[{ans = Round@Log[GoldenRatio, F Sqrt[5]]},
  ans /; Fibonacci[ans] == F]
invFib[F_Integer] := Null /; (Message[invFib::notFib, F]; False);

invFib[13]
(*  7  *)

invFib[Fibonacci[10^3]]
(*  1000  *)

invFib[Fibonacci[10^2] + 1]
(*
  invFib::notFib: 354224848179261915076 is not a Fibonacci number

  invFib[354224848179261915076]
*)
```

It only gives one solution to `Fibonacci[c] == 1`, though.  But that could be made a hard-coded special case if desired.

Answer (score 3):

One straightforward way is:

```
Select[Fibonacci[Range[100]], # <= 13 &] // Length 
7
```

If you don't want to calculate the whole range, reformulate as a minimization problem:

```
NMinimize[Abs[Max[Fibonacci[x]] - 13], x]
{8.40155*10^-10, {x -> 7.}}
```

Comment: The second solution fails for large Fibonacci numbers like `31940434634990099905`.

Comment: In the minimization, `Max` is not needed. `NMinimize[Abs[Fibonacci[x] - 13], x]` suffices.

Comment: @bbgodfrey - use the `WorkingPrecision` option: `NMinimize[Abs[Fibonacci[x] - 31940434634990099905], x, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 75]`

Answer (score 3):

We can extend @MichaelE2's approach to work for all reals greater than 1 as follows. First construct an interpolating function for small values:

```
InverseFibonacciIF = NDSolveValue[
    {Fibonacci'[n[x]] n'[x] == 1, n[1] == 2},
    n,
    {x, 1, 100}
]
```

`InverseFibonacciIF` will return the inverse for the domain $1\leq x\leq 100$. For values of $x$ larger than 100 we can just use @MichaelE2's approximation. So, an approximate answer to the inverse of the [`Fibonacci`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fibonacci) is given by the following `ansatz` function:

```
ansatz[x_Integer] := If[x<100,
    With[{r=InverseFibonacciIF[x]}, If[Fibonacci[Round[r]]===x, Round[r], SetPrecision[r, 5]]],
    With[{r=Log[GoldenRatio, x Sqrt[5]]}, If[Fibonacci[Round[r]]===x, Round[r], SetPrecision[r, Min[2+Log10[x], 10]]]]
]
ansatz[x_] := If[x<100,
    SetPrecision[InverseFibonacciIF[x], 5],
    SetPrecision[Log[GoldenRatio, x Sqrt[5]], Min[2+Log10[x], 10]]
]
```

Now, that we have an approximate answer for all reals $x\geq 1$, we can use this in [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root):

```
InverseFibonacci[x_?(GreaterEqualThan[1])] := Root[
    {Fibonacci[#] - x&, ansatz[x]}
]
```

Here are a few examples:

```
InverseFibonacci[13] //RepeatedTiming
InverseFibonacci[354224848179261915075] //RepeatedTiming
InverseFibonacci[354224848179261915076] //RepeatedTiming
InverseFibonacci[1234123019284712039487123048712304871234012384701238471203498712309487123048172034] //RepeatedTiming
N[Last @ %, 100]
Fibonacci[%]
```

> {0.00001165, 7}
>
> {0.000041, 100}
>
> {0.000052, Root[{-354224848179261915076 + Fibonacci[#1] &, 100.0000000}]}
>
> {0.000051, 
>   Root[{-1234123019284712039487123048712304871234012384701238471203498712309487123048172034 + Fibonacci[#1] &, 389.6921529}]}
>
> 389.6921528840252057657462642235668545582808149772397887018651599941173630555046083968116712648392913
>
> 1.2341230192847120394871230487123048712340123847012384712034987123094871230481720340000000000000000*10^81

And a plot:

```
Plot[InverseFibonacci[x], {x, 1, 1000}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These also work.

```
CountsBy[Fibonacci[Range[10]], # <= 13 &] // First
(* 7 *)

c = 1; While[Fibonacci[c] <= 13, c++]; c - 1
(* 7 *)
```

So does this, if `13` is a Fibonacci number.

```
Position[Fibonacci[Range[10]], 13][[1, 1]]
(* 7 *)
```

**Addendum: Timing**

Out of curiosity, I timed the methods provided in the three answers here, but with the much larger upper bound, `31940434634990099905`, the ninety-fifth Fibonacci number.  Not surprisingly `Position` is fastest but works only when the upper bound is a Fibonacci number.

```
RepeatedTiming[Position[Fibonacci[Range[100]], 31940434634990099905][[1, 1]]]
(* {0.000015, 95} *)
```

Three other methods that also involve only computing and testing an array of Fibonacci numbers require almost identical times, `0.000070`.

```
RepeatedTiming[c = 1; While[Fibonacci[c] <= 31940434634990099905, c++]; c - 1]

RepeatedTiming[CountsBy[Fibonacci[Range[100]], # <= 31940434634990099905 &] // First]

RepeatedTiming[Select[Fibonacci[Range[100]], # <= 31940434634990099905 &] // Length]
```

The last two perform algebraic computations and so, while elegant, are much slower.

```
RepeatedTiming[Solve[{Fibonacci[x] == 31940434634990099905, 1 <= x <= 100}, x, 
    Integers][[1, 1, 2]]]
(* {0.0036, 95} *)

RepeatedTiming[Round[NMinimize[Abs[Max[Fibonacci[x]] - 31940434634990099905], x, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 45][[2, 1, 2]]]]
(* {0.100, 95} *)
```

My thanks to Bob Hanlon for generalizing the last two methods to accommodate large numbers.