# Exploiting a relation among constants

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

Say I have two arbitrary real constants $p,q$ that satisfy $p^2+q^2=1$. Is there any way to easily declare this relation in *Mathematica*?

**Edit**

More specifically I have this (among others) expression:

$$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{p^4 q^4(p^2-q^2)^2}{p^4 + q^4}}}{\sqrt{p^{10}+p^2q^8+p^8(-2+q^2)+2p^4q^4(-2+q^2)+q^6(-1+q^2)^2+p^6(1+2q^4)}}$$

```
Divide[Sqrt[Divide[p^4 q^4 (p^2 - q^2)^2, p^4 + q^4]], 
 Sqrt[p^{10} + p^2 q^8 + p^8 (-2 + q^2) + 2 p^4 q^4 (-2 + q^2) + 
   q^6 (-1 + q^2)^2 + p^6 (1 + 2 q^4)]]
```

and am asking whether there is a way to have *Mathematica* reduce it using the relation $\;q^2+p^2=1$.

Comment: I am using Mathematica to do some tedious derivatives for me where the functions involved depend on arbitrary  constants $a,b$ subject to to the relation $a^2+b^2=1$ which I feel will simplify my results. I was wondering if there is any way to declare this relation in Mathematica so that it may reduce the output, if possible.

Comment: Related or a duplicate: [How Can I use Solve/Reduce Output](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/how-can-i-use-solve-reduce-output)

Comment: This is unclear what you mean by declaring. Simplifying, reducing, solving, substituting, etc.

Comment: Not really, this isn't how people normally work in Mathematica, and there's no way to declare such a relation.  This is why people think that your question is confusing.  (To be fair, `$Assumptions` is similar to what you describe, but it probably won't help you much.)  **To make the question clear:** give examples of calculations that you want to do with `a` and `b` and explain how you need to use the relationship between `a` and `b` in those calculations.  The answer to you question will depend on precisely what sorts of calculations you need to do and how this relationship will be used.

Comment: So again: the key is what you actually want to do and how you need to use $a^2+b^2=1$ in that.  It's impossible to give a useful answer without this information.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. More specifically I have this expression (among others) and am asking whether there is a way to have mathematica reduce it using the relation $q^2+p^2=1$. My apologies if my wording was inaccurate or confusing:$$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{p^4 q^4 \left(p^2-q^2\right)^2}{p^4+q^4}}}{\sqrt{p^{10}+p^2 q^8+p^8 \left(-2+q^2\right)+2 p^4 q^4 \left(-2+q^2\right)+q^6 \left(-1+q^2\right)^2+p^6 \left(1+2 q^4\right)}}.$$

Comment: please include the mathematica code for your expression. It might be possible and I (and others) might be willing to take a stab at answering it, but I am certainly not willing to enter that expression by hand into mathematica syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many possible ways to tackle this task.

```
expr = Sqrt[ ((p^4 q^4 (p^2 - q^2))/(p^4 + q^4))]/Sqrt[ p^10 + p^2 q^8 
       + p^8 (-2 + q^2) + 2 p^4 q^4 (-2 + q^2) + q^6 (-1 + q^2)^2 + p^6 (1 + 2 q^4)];
```

Standard approach uses simplification techniques like `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`, the latter appears to be unnecessary here. Let's use the former function:

```
Simplify[ expr, p^2 + q^2 == 1]
```

> ```
>  Sqrt[(p^4 q^4 (1 - 2 q^2))/(p^4 + q^4)]/Sqrt[q^2 - 5 q^4 + 8 q^6 - 4 q^8]
> ```

So we've got a slightly simplified expression, however one might be still dissatisfied with this result. Althoug one could play with `ComplexityFunction` but we provide another direct way using `Eliminate` and exploiting a formal variable `a` to eliminate `q`:

```
Eliminate[{expr == a, p^2 + q^2 == 1}, q]
```

> ```
> a^2 (-1 + 4 p^2 - 6 p^4 + 4 p^6) == p^2 (1 - p^2)
> ```

So we have an expression `a^2` (i.e. `expr^2`) written in terms of `p`. Let's now eliminate `p`:

```
Eliminate[{expr == a, p^2 + q^2 == 1}, p]
```

> ```
> a^2 (-1 + 4 q^2 - 6 q^4 + 4 q^6) == q^2 (-1 + q^2)
> ```

We can also use `Simplify` with a replacement rule exploiting a simple pattern, i.e. substituting all even powers of `p` with an expression involving only `q`:

```
Simplify[ expr /. p^b_?EvenQ /; b > 0 -> (1 - q^2)^(b/2)]
```

> ```
> Sqrt[-((q^4 (-1 + q^2)^2 (-1 + 2 q^2))/(1 - 2 q^2 + 2 q^4))]/Sqrt[q^2 - 5 q^4 
>                                                                    + 8 q^6 - 4 q^8]
> ```

Comment: My problem was in using only one equals sign, believe it or not. Thanks for your help, you saved me a bunch of time.

Comment: @D.Clark That's why you should _always_ post your code here!

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly corrected version of code I and others have used in MathGroup, StackOverflow, and MSE. It is at heart a recursive `PolynomialReduce`.

```
replacementFunction[expr_, rep_, vars_] := 
 Module[{num = Numerator[expr], den = Denominator[expr], 
   hed = Head[expr], base, expon}, 
  If[PolynomialQ[num, vars] && 
    PolynomialQ[den, vars] && ! NumberQ[den], 
   replacementFunction[num, rep, vars]/
    replacementFunction[den, rep, vars], 
   If[hed === Power && Length[expr] == 2, 
    base = replacementFunction[expr[[1]], rep, vars];
    expon = replacementFunction[expr[[2]], rep, vars];
    PolynomialReduce[base^expon, rep, vars][[2]], 
    If[Head[hed] === Symbol && 
      MemberQ[Attributes[Evaluate[hed]], NumericFunction],
     Map[replacementFunction[#, rep, vars] &, expr], 
     PolynomialReduce[expr, rep, vars][[2]]]]]]
```

On your example it will eliminate a variable. Whether this is useful depends on what you really require.

```
expr = Sqrt[((p^4 q^4 (p^2 - q^2))/(p^4 + q^4))]/
   Sqrt[p^10 + p^2 q^8 + p^8 (-2 + q^2) + 2 p^4 q^4 (-2 + q^2) + 
     q^6 (-1 + q^2)^2 + p^6 (1 + 2 q^4)];

replacementFunction[expr, p^2 + q^2 - 1, {p, q}]

(* Out[299]= Sqrt[-((q^4 (-1 + q^2)^2 (-1 + 2 q^2))/(
 1 - 2 q^2 + 2 q^4))]/Sqrt[-q^2 (-1 + q^2) (-1 + 2 q^2)^2] *)
```