# Replacing patterns (determinants) in a rational multivariate function and/or getting `replacementFunction` to work on a multi-linear expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

Given a rational multivariate function known to contain determinants, what is the best way to rewrite the function in terms of the determinants?

A simple example:

```
det[aa_] := Det[Table[x[li1, li2], {li1, aa /@ {1, 2}}, {li2, aa /@ {3, 4}}]];
origExpr = det[a]*det[b]/det[c] + det[d]*det[e]/det[f] - det[g]*det[h]/det[i];
oeet = origExpr //Expand // Together;
(* I paste the long, crappy expression at the end of this quesion *)
```

That the entries of the matrix be `x[i_,j_]` isn't necessarily important, that just happens to be the problem I'm considering -- the determinants happen to be Gram determinants.

**Question**:
Given the output of `oeet`, what is the best way to rediscover `origExpr`?

**Edit 2**: See "Edit 2" near the bottom of this post for an updated discussion of this problem.

**One solution**: This works for simple-enough examples:

```
vars = Union[Cases[oeet, x[a_[i_], _] :> a, Infinity]];(* Determine the variables *)
rep = Table[d[ti] == det[ti], {ti, vars}];
Simplify[oeet, rep]
(* (d[a] d[b])/d[c] + (d[d] d[e])/d[f] - (d[g] d[h])/d[i] *)
```

This doesn't do so well for $3\times 3$ determinants though:

```
det[aa_] := Det[Table[x[li1, li2], {li1, aa /@ {1, 2, 3}}, {li2, aa /@ {4, 5, 6}}]];
```

The analogous `Simplify[oeet, rep]` runs for over a minute before I kill it. The expressions that I'm actually manipulating are rational in the `x[_,_]`'s, and are not completely rational in in the determinants, and I think that adds complexity. (I couldn't come up with a non-trivial alteration to the minimal working example here.)

**Additional attempts**:
I also tried to use the `replacementFunction` for example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41548/6506) (from @DanielLichtblau, I think?), but it appears not to even alter `oeet`:

```
aVars =Select[Union[Cases[oeet, x[__], Infinity]],! FreeQ[#, a, Infinity] &]
(* {x[a[1], a[3]], x[a[1], a[4]], x[a[2], a[3]], x[a[2], a[4]]} *)
replacementFunction[oeet, detA - det[a], aVars] - oeet
(* 0  (* Should be detA-depdendent *) *)
```

Assuming I'm somewhow misusing the function, I tried `PolynomialReduce` which does a fairly good job on the $2\times 2$ matrices, but misses the denominators.

```
xVars = Union[Cases[oeet, x[_, _], Infinity]]
redEqns = (safe[#] - det[#]) & /@ vars
PolynomialReduce[oeet, redEqns, xVars][[2]]
(*
(safe[c] safe[f] safe[g] safe[h])/((x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] - 
      x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]]) (x[f[1], f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] - 
      x[f[1], f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]]) (x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] - 
      x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]])) - (safe[c] safe[d] safe[e]
      safe[i])/((x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] - 
      x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]]) (x[f[1], f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] - 
      x[f[1], f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]]) (x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] - 
      x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]])) - (safe[a] safe[b] safe[f]
      safe[i])/((x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] - 
      x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]]) (x[f[1], f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] - 
      x[f[1], f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]]) (x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] - 
      x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]]))
*)
```

It again takes a while on $3\times 3$ matrices.

**Edit**: Here is a simple example where the Groebner basis approach suggested in the first solution doesn't work:

```
det[aa_] := 
  Det[Table[
    x[li1, li2], {li1, aa /@ {1, 2, 3}}, {li2, aa /@ {4, 5, 6}}]];
origExpr = x[a[1], x[a[6]]] det[a] det[b]/det[c]; (* <- Alteration here *)
oeet = origExpr // Expand // Together;
varsx = Cases[oeet, x[a_[i_], _], \[Infinity]];
vars = Union[Cases[oeet, x[a_[i_], _] :> a, \[Infinity]]];
rep = Table[d[ti] == det[ti], {ti, vars}];
GroebnerBasis[{w == oeet}~Join~rep, w, varsx]
(* {} *)
```

It does work if I know to remove `x[a[1],a[6]]` from the "Elimination" argument of `GroebnerBasis`:

```
GroebnerBasis[{w == oeet}~Join~rep, w,DeleteCases[varsx, x[a[1], a[6]]]]
(* {w d[c] - d[a] d[b] x[a[1], a[6]]} *)
```

but given a general polynomial in the `x[_,_]`'s, I won't know which `x[_,_]`'s to remove from the elimination argument of `GroebnerBasis`. I guess in general I'm looking for something that can implement polynomial changes of variables in a multivariate rational function.

**Edit 2**:
I'm now pretty sure the best way to do this is with the `replacementFunction` [I already referenced](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41548/6506). The function is effectively an iterative `PolynomialReduce`. It doesn't seem to like exactly multi-linear functions, such as determinants, however. 
Here's a version of `replacementFunction` that has an optional fourth argument that when set to `ON` prints output to track what's happening. [This link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41548/6506) has the barebones version of the function.

```
replacementFunction // ClearAll;
replacementFunction[expr_, rep_, vars_, TS_: 0] :=
  Module[
   {num = Numerator[expr], den = Denominator[expr], hed = Head[expr], 
    base, expon, out, tsp}
   ,
   tsp[x_] := If[TS === ON, Print[x];];
   If[
        PolynomialQ[num, vars] && PolynomialQ[den, vars] && ! NumberQ[den]
        ,
        tsp["T1 - A rational function"];
        tsp[expr];
        replacementFunction[num, rep, vars, TS]/replacementFunction[den, rep, vars, TS]
        ,
        tsp["F1 - Not a rational function"];
        tsp[expr];
        If[
            hed === Power && Length[expr] == 2
            ,
            tsp["T2 - A power function"];
            tsp[expr];
            base = replacementFunction[expr[[1]], rep, vars, TS];
            expon = replacementFunction[expr[[2]], rep, vars, TS];
            out = PolynomialReduce[base^expon, rep, vars];
            tsp["===T2out==="];
            tsp[out // Flatten // TableForm];
            out[[2]]
            ,
            tsp["F2 - Not a power function"];
            tsp[expr];
            If[
                Head[hed] === Symbol && MemberQ[Attributes[Evaluate[hed]], NumericFunction]
                ,
                tsp["T3 - A numeric function"];
                tsp[expr];
                Map[replacementFunction[#, rep, vars, TS] &, expr]
                ,
                tsp["F3 - Not a numeric function"];
                tsp["***Reduce***"];
                tsp["Divide ", expr];
                tsp["by ", rep];
                out = PolynomialReduce[expr, rep, vars];
                tsp["===out==="];
                tsp[out // Flatten // TableForm];
                out[[2]]
                ], TS
            ]
        ]
   ];
```

This doesn't work on a simple determinant:

```
expr = (a[1, 1] a[2, 2] - a[1, 2] a[2, 1]);
replacementFunction[expr, expr + d, Variables[expr]]
(* Actually running will print out what the function is doing *)
(* -a[1, 2] a[2, 1] + a[1, 1] a[2, 2] (*Output*)*)
```

It appears to work when the expression is not multi-linear:

```
exprA = (a[1, 1] a[2, 2] - a[1, 2] a[2, 1]);
exprB = (b[1, 1] b[2, 2] - b[1, 2] b[2, 1]);
replacementFunction[(exprA + exprB)^2, {exprA - dA, exprB - dB}, Join[Variables[exprA],Variables[exprB]]]
(* dA^2 + 2 dA dB + dB^2 *)
```

But again breaks when the expression is multi-linear (like a determinant is):

```
replacementFunction[exprA exprB, {exprA - dA, exprB - dB},Join[Variables[exprA],Variables[exprB]]]
(* (-a[1, 2] a[2, 1] + a[1, 1] a[2, 2]) (-b[1, 2] b[2, 1] + b[1, 1] b[2, 2]) *)
```

**Updated question**: How do I get `replacementFunction` to work on multi-linear expressions such as determinants.

It appears to already solve the more general problem of changing variables in a polynomial. From what I can tell, `replacementFunction` jumps through every part at every level of the expression and performs `PolynomialReduce` where it can. I can't currently see why it doesn't catch the multi-linear terms.

Below is the crappy output of `oeet`.

```
(* The output from oeet = origExpr //Expand // Together:
(x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[f[1], f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[g[1], 
     g[4]] x[g[2], g[3]] x[h[1], h[4]] x[h[2], h[3]] - 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[f[1], f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[g[1], 
     g[4]] x[g[2], g[3]] x[h[1], h[4]] x[h[2], h[3]] - 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[f[1], f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[g[1], 
     g[4]] x[g[2], g[3]] x[h[1], h[4]] x[h[2], h[3]] + 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[f[1], f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[g[1], 
     g[4]] x[g[2], g[3]] x[h[1], h[4]] x[h[2], h[3]] - 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[f[1], f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[g[1], 
     g[3]] x[g[2], g[4]] x[h[1], h[4]] x[h[2], h[3]] + 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[f[1], f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[g[1], 
     g[3]] x[g[2], g[4]] x[h[1], h[4]] x[h[2], h[3]] + 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[f[1], f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[g[1], 
     g[3]] x[g[2], g[4]] x[h[1], h[4]] x[h[2], h[3]] - 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[f[1], f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[g[1], 
     g[3]] x[g[2], g[4]] x[h[1], h[4]] x[h[2], h[3]] - 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[f[1], f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[g[1], 
     g[4]] x[g[2], g[3]] x[h[1], h[3]] x[h[2], h[4]] + 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[f[1], f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[g[1], 
     g[4]] x[g[2], g[3]] x[h[1], h[3]] x[h[2], h[4]] + 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[f[1], f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[g[1], 
     g[4]] x[g[2], g[3]] x[h[1], h[3]] x[h[2], h[4]] - 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[f[1], f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[g[1], 
     g[4]] x[g[2], g[3]] x[h[1], h[3]] x[h[2], h[4]] + 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[f[1], f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[g[1], 
     g[3]] x[g[2], g[4]] x[h[1], h[3]] x[h[2], h[4]] - 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[f[1], f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[g[1], 
     g[3]] x[g[2], g[4]] x[h[1], h[3]] x[h[2], h[4]] - 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[f[1], f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[g[1], 
     g[3]] x[g[2], g[4]] x[h[1], h[3]] x[h[2], h[4]] + 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[f[1], f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[g[1], 
     g[3]] x[g[2], g[4]] x[h[1], h[3]] x[h[2], h[4]] - 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[d[1], d[4]] x[d[2], d[3]] x[e[1], 
     e[4]] x[e[2], e[3]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] + 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[d[1], d[4]] x[d[2], d[3]] x[e[1], 
     e[4]] x[e[2], e[3]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] + 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[d[1], d[3]] x[d[2], d[4]] x[e[1], 
     e[4]] x[e[2], e[3]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] - 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[d[1], d[3]] x[d[2], d[4]] x[e[1], 
     e[4]] x[e[2], e[3]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] + 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[d[1], d[4]] x[d[2], d[3]] x[e[1], 
     e[3]] x[e[2], e[4]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] - 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[d[1], d[4]] x[d[2], d[3]] x[e[1], 
     e[3]] x[e[2], e[4]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] - 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[d[1], d[3]] x[d[2], d[4]] x[e[1], 
     e[3]] x[e[2], e[4]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] + 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[d[1], d[3]] x[d[2], d[4]] x[e[1], 
     e[3]] x[e[2], e[4]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] - 
   x[a[1], a[4]] x[a[2], a[3]] x[b[1], b[4]] x[b[2], b[3]] x[f[1], 
     f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] + 
   x[a[1], a[3]] x[a[2], a[4]] x[b[1], b[4]] x[b[2], b[3]] x[f[1], 
     f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] + 
   x[a[1], a[4]] x[a[2], a[3]] x[b[1], b[3]] x[b[2], b[4]] x[f[1], 
     f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] - 
   x[a[1], a[3]] x[a[2], a[4]] x[b[1], b[3]] x[b[2], b[4]] x[f[1], 
     f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] + 
   x[a[1], a[4]] x[a[2], a[3]] x[b[1], b[4]] x[b[2], b[3]] x[f[1], 
     f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] - 
   x[a[1], a[3]] x[a[2], a[4]] x[b[1], b[4]] x[b[2], b[3]] x[f[1], 
     f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] - 
   x[a[1], a[4]] x[a[2], a[3]] x[b[1], b[3]] x[b[2], b[4]] x[f[1], 
     f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] + 
   x[a[1], a[3]] x[a[2], a[4]] x[b[1], b[3]] x[b[2], b[4]] x[f[1], 
     f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] + 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[d[1], d[4]] x[d[2], d[3]] x[e[1], 
     e[4]] x[e[2], e[3]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] - 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[d[1], d[4]] x[d[2], d[3]] x[e[1], 
     e[4]] x[e[2], e[3]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] - 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[d[1], d[3]] x[d[2], d[4]] x[e[1], 
     e[4]] x[e[2], e[3]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] + 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[d[1], d[3]] x[d[2], d[4]] x[e[1], 
     e[4]] x[e[2], e[3]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] - 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[d[1], d[4]] x[d[2], d[3]] x[e[1], 
     e[3]] x[e[2], e[4]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] + 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[d[1], d[4]] x[d[2], d[3]] x[e[1], 
     e[3]] x[e[2], e[4]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] + 
   x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] x[d[1], d[3]] x[d[2], d[4]] x[e[1], 
     e[3]] x[e[2], e[4]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] - 
   x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]] x[d[1], d[3]] x[d[2], d[4]] x[e[1], 
     e[3]] x[e[2], e[4]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] + 
   x[a[1], a[4]] x[a[2], a[3]] x[b[1], b[4]] x[b[2], b[3]] x[f[1], 
     f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] - 
   x[a[1], a[3]] x[a[2], a[4]] x[b[1], b[4]] x[b[2], b[3]] x[f[1], 
     f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] - 
   x[a[1], a[4]] x[a[2], a[3]] x[b[1], b[3]] x[b[2], b[4]] x[f[1], 
     f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] + 
   x[a[1], a[3]] x[a[2], a[4]] x[b[1], b[3]] x[b[2], b[4]] x[f[1], 
     f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] - 
   x[a[1], a[4]] x[a[2], a[3]] x[b[1], b[4]] x[b[2], b[3]] x[f[1], 
     f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] + 
   x[a[1], a[3]] x[a[2], a[4]] x[b[1], b[4]] x[b[2], b[3]] x[f[1], 
     f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] + 
   x[a[1], a[4]] x[a[2], a[3]] x[b[1], b[3]] x[b[2], b[4]] x[f[1], 
     f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]] - 
   x[a[1], a[3]] x[a[2], a[4]] x[b[1], b[3]] x[b[2], b[4]] x[f[1], 
     f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]] x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], 
     i[4]])/((x[c[1], c[4]] x[c[2], c[3]] - 
     x[c[1], c[3]] x[c[2], c[4]]) (x[f[1], f[4]] x[f[2], f[3]] - 
     x[f[1], f[3]] x[f[2], f[4]]) (x[i[1], i[4]] x[i[2], i[3]] - 
     x[i[1], i[3]] x[i[2], i[4]]))
*)
```

Comment: This appears to be a problem that [periodically resurfaces](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11701/6506). It looks like PolynomialReduce tends to be the answer...

Answer (score 2):

As usual, `GroebnerBasis[]` is very useful here:

```
det[aa_] := Det[Table[x[li1, li2], {li1, aa /@ {1, 2, 3}}, {li2, aa /@ {4, 5, 6}}]];

origExpr = det[a] det[b]/det[c] + det[d] det[e]/det[f] - det[g] det[h]/det[i];
oeet = origExpr // Expand // Together;

varsx = Cases[oeet, x[a_[i_], _], ∞];
vars = Union[Cases[oeet, x[a_[i_], _] :> a, ∞]];
rep = Table[d[ti] == det[ti], {ti, vars}];

Solve[First[GroebnerBasis[{w == oeet} ~Join~ rep, w, varsx]] == 0, w] // Simplify
   {{w -> (d[a] d[b])/d[c] + (d[d] d[e])/d[f] - (d[g] d[h])/d[i]}}
```

Comment: This is a good first step, but there's a bit of a hiccup. Taking `origExpr = x[a[1], x[a[2]]] det[a]*det[b]/det[c] + det[d]*det[e]/det[f] - 
 det[g]*det[h]/det[i]` requires I know in advance to exclude `x[a[1], x[a[2]]]` from `varsx`. Given `oeet`, I may not know a priori which `x[_,_]`'s can/can not be eliminated.

Comment: Well, that's why the code just picks out all the `x`'s (as you did) and feeds the entire list into `GroebnerBasis[]`, leaving it to figure out how to perform the required eliminations.

Comment: What I meant to say is that the solution you propose: `GroebnerBasis[{w == oeet}~Join~rep, w, varsx]` returns `{}` when the original expression has simple additional `x[_,_]` dependence: `origExpr = x[a[1], x[a[6]]] det[a]*det[b]/det[c] + det[d]*det[e]/det[f] - 
  det[g]*det[h]/det[i]`. If I happen know to remove `x[a[1], x[a[6]]]` from `varsx` by hand, then the result is as desired. But for a generic expression, I don't know which `x[_,_]`'s to exclude from the third argument of `GroebnerBasis`. Is there some way to address this issue as well?

Comment: So, your expressions in general may have `x` objects that were not present in the `det` objects? If so, you really should have mentioned that to begin with in your question.

Comment: Yes. And it actually doesn't affect the `Simplify[oeet, rep]` I originally included for the $2\times 2$ matrices, so I assumed it wouldn't affect other solutions either. Maybe a bad assumption.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. The new factor `x[a[1],a[6]]` does appear in `det[a]`. My original augmented example with `x[a[1],a[2]]` does not. Either way the Groebner basis method doesn't work. A best case scenario would work even for `x[_,_]` that are in none of the `det[_]`s or any other functional dependence which does not appear in any of the `det[_]`s.

Comment: Just for reference, can you edit your question to include the example where the Gröbner approach goes bust?