# Making multi-linear polynomial change of variables (simplifications) by updating `replacementFunction`

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

This is an evolution of [one of my previous questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118437/6506); I've got a partial answer to that question and now have a much cleaner question to ask:

**Question**: What changes to `replacementFunction` (defined below) are required for it work on determinant-like expressions?

The `replacementFunction` has shown up multiple times. There's a barebones version of it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41548/6506). At the bottom of this question, I include a version of it with an optional fourth argument that when set to `ON` prints what the function is doing (to aid any noble souls who attempt to assist).

`replacementFunction` uses `PolynomialReduce` to rewrite sub-expressions in a user-defined way. I am trying to use it on determinant-like expressions, but the iterative structure of `replacementFunction` appears to miss something on expressions with `Head[expr]===Plus`.

An example where `replacementFunction` works:

```
exprA = (a[1, 1] a[2, 2] + a[1, 2] a[2, 1]);
replacementFunction[exprA^2, {exprA - detA}, Variables[exprA], ON]
(*detA^2*)
```

and an example where it doesn't work:

```
exprA = (a[1, 1] a[2, 2] + a[1, 2] a[2, 1]);
replacementFunction[exprA, {exprA - detA}, Variables[exprA], ON]
(* a[1, 1] a[2, 2] + a[1, 2] a[2, 1] *)
```

The only difference is `exprA` vs. `exprA^2` in the first argument of `replacementFunction`. I think this has to do with the fact that `replacementFunction` performs a `PolynomialReduce` on expressions with `hed===Power`, but doesn't appear to do so for expressions with `hed===Plus`, but I can't figure out how to implement this consistently.

Here is the printing version or `replacementFunction`:

```
(* Definition of replacement function *)
replacementFunction // ClearAll;
replacementFunction[expr_, rep_, vars_, TS_: 0] :=
  Module[
   {num = Numerator[expr], den = Denominator[expr], hed = Head[expr], 
    base, expon, out, tsp, pr}
   ,
   tsp[x_] := If[TS === ON, Print[x];];
   pr := PolynomialReduce[expr, rep, vars];
   If[
        PolynomialQ[num, vars] && PolynomialQ[den, vars] && ! NumberQ[den]
        ,
        tsp["T1 - A rational function"];
        tsp[expr];
        out = replacementFunction[num, rep, vars, TS]/replacementFunction[den, rep, vars, TS];
        tsp["===T1 out==="];
        tsp[out // Flatten // TableForm];
        out
        ,
        tsp["F1 - Not a rational function"];
        tsp[expr];
        If[
            hed === Power && Length[expr] == 2
            ,
            tsp["T2 - A power function"];
            tsp[expr];
            base = replacementFunction[expr[[1]], rep, vars, TS];
            expon = replacementFunction[expr[[2]], rep, vars, TS];
            out = PolynomialReduce[base^expon, rep, vars];
            tsp["===T2 out==="];
            tsp[out // Flatten // TableForm];
            out[[2]]
            ,
            tsp["F2 - Not a power function"];
            tsp[expr];
            If[
                Head[hed] === Symbol && MemberQ[Attributes[Evaluate[hed]], NumericFunction]
                ,
                tsp["T3 - A numeric function"];
                tsp[expr];
                Map[replacementFunction[#, rep, vars, TS] &, expr]
                ,
                tsp["F3 - Not a numeric function"];
                tsp["***Reduce***"];
                tsp["Divide ", expr];
                tsp["by ", rep];
                out = pr(*PolynomialReduce*);
                tsp["===T3 out==="];
                tsp[out // Flatten // TableForm];
                out[[2]]
                ]
            ]
        ]
   ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to update this function to correctly work on multi-linear expressions.

All that's required is one additional call of `PolynomialReduce` in the third nested `If` statement. This mirrors the way the second `If` statement handles the power case. It might be that there should be a similar treatment for the division case (the first `If` statement), but I haven't run into problems there.

For completeness, I include an updated version of the function, without the printing option (to increase speed).

```
replacementFunction // ClearAll;
replacementFunction[expr_, rep_, vars_] :=
  Module[
   {num = Numerator[expr], den = Denominator[expr], hed = Head[expr], 
    base, expon, iterative}
   ,
   If[
        PolynomialQ[num, vars] && PolynomialQ[den, vars] && ! NumberQ[den]
        ,
        replacementFunction[num, rep, vars]/
        replacementFunction[den, rep, vars];
        ,
        If[
            hed === Power && Length[expr] == 2
            ,
            base = replacementFunction[expr[[1]], rep, vars];
            expon = replacementFunction[expr[[2]], rep, vars];
            PolynomialReduce[base^expon, rep, vars][[2]]
            ,
            If[
                Head[hed] === Symbol && 
                MemberQ[Attributes[Evaluate[hed]], NumericFunction]
                ,
                (* Alteration here *)
                iterative = Map[replacementFunction[#, rep, vars] &, expr];
                PolynomialReduce[iterative, rep, vars][[2]]
                ,
                PolynomialReduce[expr, rep, vars][[2]]
                ]
            ]
        ]
   ];
```

Comment: Your nested `If` statements can be written in flattened form using `Which`

Comment: Agreed! I posted with the `If`s because that's how the function has appeared on here in the past.