# Error when solving equations constructed with Table

Tags: equation-solving

I have a couple of questions about the problem I am trying to solve

```
n = 7;
alpha = 0.01; c = 10;

atable = Table[a[i], {i, 0, n}]; 
Solu = y^Range[0, n].atable;

Leftequ = Solu; 
Rightequ =  A y^2 +  B y + DD + 1/2/alpha Integrate[Solu^2, y];

Lec = CoefficientList[Leftequ, y];
Rec = CoefficientList[Rightequ, y];

Lec = PadRight[Lec, Min[Length[Lec], Length[Rec]]];
Rec = PadRight[Rec, Min[Length[Lec], Length[Rec]]];

eqs = Lec == Rec;

Sol = Solve[eqs, atable]
```

If I check `a[0]` it will show that `a[0]=a[0]`, but I want to set it to `a[0] = DD`. This is probably a mistake I overlooked, but nevertheless could not find it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer might should be helpful: [Using the result of functions that return replacement rules](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/131).

Comment: Possible duplicates:  [(3175)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3175/121), [(6669)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6669/121), [(9035)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9035/121).

Answer (score 1):

The result you see is a list of replacement rules (check documentation).  If you want to pull a specific value out do something like this...

```
a[0] /. Sol[[1]]
```

which in this case will give you DD.

Solve will not assign the value DD to a[0], the replacement rules tell you what they're value is in the solution.  If mathematica did assign values to a[0], a[1]... etc when you ran solve the second time you run it everything would break because a[0] wouldn't be a free variable it would be DD.

Note: generally best to use lower-case starting names, sol rather than Sol, rec rather than Rec as all Mathematica's own symbols start with Capital letters and eventually you'll hit one and get an error.