# Use FindRoot solution as number in function

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I would like to save a number that I gain with FindRoot so that I can use it in another function. I tried:

```
alph := FindRoot[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, 2}]
f[x_] := alph*x
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

This does not work because `alph` is not a number but an expression `{x -> 2.40483}`. So how do I do this correctly?

Comment: alph =x/.FindRoot[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, 2}]

Comment: See also: [(3175)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3175/121), [(6669)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6669/121), [(9035)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9035/121)